# Importing a function within a function for use with timeit

Tags: python, factorial, scoping, timeit

I am timing the speed of several functions and found the `timeit` module to be most useful as it returns an average. I can use what I am doing fine outside of a function but when I try to clean up my code and put it into a function AND clear my notebook outputs I get an `ImportError`.

So this is a scoping issue I'm fairly certain. I have of course made sure my notebook cells with my factorial functions have been run, so I don't know how my functions can't be seen by `calling_functions(x,y,z)`

Hope that's not too much to ask for some help with, thanks in advance.

Outside of function, works fine:

```
# Declaring variables
functions = [factorial_iterative, factorial_non_tail, factorial_tail, factorial_memoization] # Which functions to run, no arguments
num_of_factorial = 100 # Factorial of which number to calculate, suggest 10-100
num_of_runs = 10000 # How many runs per factorial, suggest 10-10000

# Declaring lists to be filled with runtime
factorial_iterative_time = []
factorial_non_tail_time = []
factorial_tail_time = []
factorial_memoization_time = []


for function in functions: # Iterating over functions list
    for i in range(1,num_of_factorial,1): # Iterating through number of factorials to calculate
        if __name__ == '__main__': # Importing functions into local scope. ref:https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html
            if function == factorial_iterative: # Appending to correct list
                # Append output from timeit to correct list. i is factorial number, import function and i from main, run current iteration for defined many times
                factorial_iterative_time.append(timeit.timeit("function(i)", setup="from __main__ import function, i", number=num_of_runs))
            if function == factorial_non_tail:
                factorial_non_tail_time.append(timeit.timeit("function(i)", setup="from __main__ import function, i", number=num_of_runs))
            if function == factorial_tail:
                factorial_tail_time.append(timeit.timeit("function(i)", setup="from __main__ import function, i", number=num_of_runs))
            if function == factorial_memoization:
                factorial_memoization_time.append(timeit.timeit("function(i)", setup="from __main__ import function, i", number=num_of_runs))
```

Inside a function, broken in a clean notebook:

```
def calling_functions(function, num_of_factorial=100, num_of_runs=10000):
    times = []
    for i in range(1,num_of_factorial,1): # Iterating through number of factorials to calculate
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            times.append(timeit.timeit("function(i)", setup="from __main__ import function, i", number=num_of_runs))
    return (times) 

factorial_non_tail_time = calling_functions(factorial_non_tail)

ImportError: cannot import name 'function' from '__main__' (unknown location)
```